# Poetic translation for "I'll be your Manolete, if you'll be my Lupe"

Tags: traducción

I want to find a poetic translation for this phrase to use in some writing and can't get it right.

> I'll be your Manolete, if you'll be my Lupe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can never go wrong with Miguel Hernandez:

¿A dónde iré que no vaya

mi perdición a buscar?

Tu destino es de la playa

y mi vocación del mar.

---

The word-by-word of your phrase is clunky: "*Yo seré tu Manolete si tu eres mi Lupe*." Instead, try

> `Yo haré de Manolete a tu Lupe.`
>   which is shorter and thus more effective. The figurative meaning is something like "I will counter the character of Manolete to your playing the Lupe part.

Comment: In this case I see nothing wrong with the literal translation and I like it better than your alternative offer. But this is a matter of taste, I guess.